# How to create a variable that is present in test data set but not in train?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-imputation, train

Im try to do a classification but i have a variable production budget which is present in test dataset and not in train. so how do i proceed. could i impute that variable somehow. i dont want to drop the variable from test db. one way i can think is by combining test and train and doing a knn imputation, but the train is too large dataset and test is like 10% of it, so it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have something which is not at all in the train-dataset in the model.

You can split the test data further and then use one of the split as train, but in general, more data gives better result and here you have 9 times train data. I know it seems that you might lose a lot of information when not using that variable, but usually its not that case.

Theoritically you can impute the variable using the test data, but

- It is wrong to look into test data for anything but validation. (that too within limit or else one tends to overfit on test).
- Since you have 90% missing values, you'd be doing a lot of approximation and the quality would be poor.

Comment: i understand that the variables should be common across train and test. but my question pertain to creation of variable using any technique.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli see my edit

Comment: You can split the test data further and then use one of the split as train. that's a nice advice but how would i get the class labels for the data i have split using the test data.

Comment: I assumed that you have class labels for your test data, If you don't it, then I guess you can not use the variable in any supervised model

Comment: its like i have a train data set with class label and i have to predict the same for the test data. now what im interested is in, how do i go about creating a variable like production budget, which is there in test. i know its a little overwhelming but i would like to do that. my other variable are name display_name production_year movie_sequel creative_type source production_method. basically i think there would be some kind of link with production method or so.

Comment: If you're imputing a variable using other existing variables, you are not adding any new information to the dataset. A test to confirm that would be 1. Train a regression model with target as production budget, and other variable as predictor. Then creating  two models, one with the estimated variable, other without. But I would still like to iterate that even if this gives you somewhat better result, you wont see that in entirely unseen data

Comment: yeah variable deduced from the existing variable would infact result in mc. so i guess i have to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

The training and test data sets have to contain all the same variables.  In any case, training and test data should be randomly divided from the whole data set, in which case the situation you describe could not exist.

Comment: test dataset is usually external to the train dataset. validation dataset is the one that has to be randomly divided from the train dataset. anyways what happens if i encounter a new variable in test and would like to have it in my train too.

Comment: No. If you make three data sets, all three should be randomly split from one. There is no solution to the problem you state because it indicates a much bigger problem - you don't have proper train and test data sets.

Comment: what if the test data comes from the future observation and the train comes from the historical obs. basically you are training your model on  historical obs and trying to predict it on future obs.

Comment: That's not really test data, as I understand the term, but, in any case, you can't have another variable in there.  Just drop that variable.